# AG-GRID How to use setFilterModel with treeList

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-set-tree-list/

Following these instructions to setup a treeList filter for a date column. Filters by year -> month -> date. Anyone know how to use gridApi.setFilterModel to programmatically set this filter?

Everything else about my treeList filter works. Tried something like this but doesn't work:

```
this.gridApi.setFilterModel({
  'viewModelsMetadata.modifiedAt': {
    filterType: 'set',
    values: [2023],
  },
});
```